# Understanding the need for Residues of Differentials

Tags: complex-analysis

I am currently following Serge Lange's Introduction to Complex Analysis at a Graduate Level and I am currently not understanding what the author is getting at. More specifically, I am not following this introductory part

[image]

I don't understand what does the chain rule have to do with residues in the context of evaluating integrals.

Could someone explain to me the need for residues of differentials and moreover, if possible, explain the need for **meromorphic differentials** and **local coordinates** as I have had a look and non of this seems intuitive to me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The idea behind local coordinates and the chain rule is that you want a rule for calculating the residues when you change coordinate systems. There are many, many different ways to give coordinates to a manifold, and you want to be able to compute in different coordinate systems. It may be helpful to learn a little geometry before diving into this theory.

Comment: If $\omega$ is a meromorphic $1$-form on a Riemann surface $X$, what do people want to do? Take a coordinate system $(U,z)$ around a pole $a \in X$ of $\omega$, write $\omega = f\,{\rm d}z$, and set ${\rm Res}(\omega; a)\doteq {\rm Res}(f;a)$, where the residue on the right is the one you know for functions, via Laurent series. Checking that this definition is independent of the choice of $(U,z)$ should use the chain rule.

Comment: Hi @user951252 thank you for the comment. Do you have any suggests for resources on this topic to read on?

Comment: hey @IvoTerek thank you for the comment. I am having trouble realizing the significance of this, and moreover, the use within analysis. For the past few days I have been looking for online lectures and resources on the matter but I can't seem to find any, that is on examples of the use of residues of differentials. Do you know where I can find such examples?

Comment: The first place that came to mind is Forster's *Lectures on Riemann Surfaces*, might be worth checking.