# Worked Exercises about Residues of Differentials

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, reference-request, residue-calculus

I would first like to say that if this post is inappropriate for this StackExchange please let me know and I will remove it.

A few days ago I posted a question asking about [Understanding the need for Residues of Differentials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4206362/understanding-the-need-for-residues-of-differentials) and I got a couple of comments with some ideas and a suggestion for me to look at geometry first.

My issue is that I can't seem to find a lot of information on Residues of Differentials, and moreover, no worked exercises on their use within complex analysis. The book that I am following, Serge Lang's Introduction to Complex Analysis at a Graduate Level, does have some exercises, however, they are not worked.

I did ask the people who commented on my original post if they could share any usefull resources on this matter but both of them have yet to respond (I am not too sure if the comment system notifies people on replies?).

**My question:** Are there any standard examples of the use of differentials of residues in complex analysis that one should know? Moreover,  does anybody have any resources/notes ,that they are willing to share, on the topic that also include worked exercises?